# C# Dictionary.ContainsKey() always returns false

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, dictionary

I have a Dictionary and every time I call the ContainsKey method it returns false. Take the following example

```
 Boolean found = dict.ContainsKey(new Group("group1", "test"));
```

The found variable is false eventhough the visual studio debugger shows that a Group with the name "group1" and type "test" is present in dict. What is going on?

My Group class has two String fields (type and name) and I override the Equals method

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    Group otherGroup = (Group)obj;
    return this.name == otherGroup.name && this.type == otherGroup.type;
}
```

Comment: And GetHashCode is overriden too?

Comment: It looks like you've been burned by [not overriding GetHashCode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overriden-in-c#371348).

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overriden-in-c

Comment: If you override `Equals` you should always also override `GetHashCode` so that it returns a unique value for your `Group` objects. Also, duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129497/c-dictionary-containskey

Comment: @CoryLarson Thanks for the question reference; I didn't find that one in my search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should override [GetHashCode method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx)

An example of HashMethod for a class containing 2 string properties

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        return ((name != null ? name.GetHashCode() : 0)*397) ^ (type != null ? type.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to C# what does the unchecked keyword do? Also, why are you only multiplying the name hash code by 397?

Comment: The unchecked keyword is used to suppress overflow-checking for integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions.

Comment: 397 is a prime number. http://computinglife.wordpress.com/2008/11/20/why-do-hash-functions-use-prime-numbers/

Comment: I got why you choose to use 397 but I'm confused as to why you only multiplied the name hash code by 397 and not the type hash code as well?

Comment: This hash method is generated by Resharper. I think you should ask them directly ;)

Answer (score 4):

You need to override `GetHashCode()`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182358(v=vs.80).aspx

> GetHashCode returns a value based on the current instance that is suited for hashing algorithms and data structures such as a hash table. Two objects that are the same type and are equal must return the same hash code to ensure that instances of System.Collections.HashTable and **System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary** work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question already have an accepted answer but i'll share my **dirty** solution too.

```
Boolean found = 
   dict.Keys.Any(key => 
                 key.Equals("key", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```